# Can anyone work out why having changed style CSS on this wordpress site the colours on this page haven't changed?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to change the colour of the search box and social network links on this wordpress theme. I've done plenty of web development before, but this is my first time using wordpress. The original colour on the style CSS was orange. You can see below I have changed it to green, however the change just isn't taking effect.

The theme is "restauranteur"

And here's the site:
[www.playlistforlife.org.uk/wordpress](http://www.playlistforlife.org.uk/wordpress)

```
/******************************************************************
SEARCH BOX
******************************************************************/

#search-box-wrap {
background-color: #8bb295;
height: 50px;
margin-left: -33px;
margin-right: -33px;
display: none;

}

#search-box {
position: relative;
width: 96%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 2%;
max-width: 1062px;
-webkit-box-sizing : border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing : border-box; 
-o-box-sizing : border-box; 
box-sizing : border-box;
}

#search-box #searchform {
float: right;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#search-box #searchform label {
display: none;
}

#s {
height: 30px;
font-size: 1.2em;
background: url(library/images/icon-search.png) no-repeat 7px 7px #fff;
padding: 5px 7px 5px 30px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #d0d0d0 inset;
min-width: 400px;
outline: none;
margin-right: -4px;
}
.post-content #s {
    min-width: 50%;
}

#searchform input[type=submit] {
height: 30px;
background-color: #8bb295;
font-family: "Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
border: 0;
padding: 3px 10px;
}

#search-box #close-x {
float: right;
width: 23px;
height: 23px;
background-color: #8bb295;
font-family: "Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 21px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}

/******************************************************************
SOCIAL MEDIA BUTTONS STYLES
******************************************************************/

#social-media {
display: inline-block;
width: 39%;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: bottom;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#social-media a,
#search-icon {
    background-color: #8bb295;
    width: 30px;
    height: 29px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    text-indent: 9999px;
    outline: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: did u try **empty cache and hard reload**??

Comment: I've cleared it and tried different browsers and devices. (out of interest are the search box and social network links green or orange on your screens?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can change the color in theme options in your  WP theme. or give the code as `!important`

```
#social-media a, #search-icon {
    background-color: #8BB295 !important;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 29px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    outline: medium none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 9999px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 30px;
}

#search-box-wrap {
    background-color: #8BB295 !important;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -33px;
    margin-right: -33px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule that's causing it.

/wordpress/ #2 line 35

```
#search-box-wrap, #social-media a, #search-icon, .post-content a.more-link, .pagination a:hover, .pagination span.current, #comment-nav-above a, #comment-nav-below a, #nav-above a, #nav-below a, #image-navigation a, .commentlist .comment-reply-link, .commentlist .comment-reply-login, #respond #submit, .grid-box .menu-price {
  background-color: #E68B2B;
}
```

Comment: Hi popovitsj, thanks - sorry i'm so new to wp - which file are you referring to when you say "/wordpress/ #2 line 35"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know either. This is just what Firebug is saying.

Answer (score 0):

open the header.php file. write css style before `</head>` tag as

```
<style>
#search-box-wrap {
background-color: #8bb295;
}
#social-media a, #search-icon {
background-color: #8bb295;
}
</style>
```

It will work.